# How can we implement Tree or Nested iron-list in polymer 1.0?

Tags: element, nested-lists, polymer-1.0

I want to create a tree/nested list element so that I can load/ parse data with recursion..

Is there any element available for creating tree?? If this can be achieved by using iron-list, the what should be the JSON data structure and How to parse it to load Nested List... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Root
|
Item-1
  |..Item-2
  |..Item-3
  |..Item-4
       |..Item-5
       |    |..Item-6
       |..Item-7